# Can't focus fancybox iframe input

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

So I'm using fancybox to load up a login iframe, and I would like it onComplete to bring focus to the username field. If someone could take a look at this code and let me know what's wrong, that'd be great.

Gracias.

```
/* Function to resize the height of the fancybox window */
(function($){ $.fn.resize = function(width, height) { 
if (!width || (width == "inherit")) inner_width = parent.$("#fancybox-inner").width();
if (!height || (height == "inherit")) inner_height = parent.$("#fancybox-inner").height();
inner_width = width;
outer_width = (inner_width + 14);
inner_height = height;
outer_height = (inner_height + 14);
parent.$("#fancybox-inner").css({'width':inner_width, 'height':inner_height});
parent.$("#fancybox-outer").css({'width':outer_width, 'height':outer_height});
}
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){

var pasturl = parent.location.href;

$("a.iframe#register").fancybox({
    'transitionIn'          :   'fade',
    'transitionOut'         :   'fade',
    'speedIn'                       : 600,
    'speedOut'                  : 350,
    'width'                         : 450,
    'height'                        : 385,
    'scrolling'                 : 'no',
    'autoScale'                 : false,
    'autoDimensions'        : false,
    'overlayShow'               : true,
    'overlayOpacity'        : 0.7,
    'padding'                       : 7,
    'hideOnContentClick': false,
    'titleShow'                 : false,
    'onStart'                       : function() {
                                                    $.fn.resize(450,385);
                                                },
    'onComplete'                : function() {
                                                    $("#realname").focus();
                                                },
    'onClosed'                  : function() {
                                                    $(".warningmsg").hide();
                                                    $(".errormsg").hide();
                                                    $(".successfulmsg").hide();
                                                }
});

$("a.iframe#login").fancybox({
    'transitionIn'          :   'fade',
    'transitionOut'         :   'fade',
    'speedIn'                       : 600,
    'speedOut'                  : 350,
    'width'                         : 400,
    'height'                        : 250,
    'scrolling'                 : 'no',
    'autoScale'                 : false,
    'overlayShow'               : true,
    'overlayOpacity'        : 0.7,
    'padding'                       : 7,
    'hideOnContentClick': false,
    'titleShow'                 : false,
    'onStart'                       : function() {
                                                    $.fn.resize(400,250);
                                                },
    'onComplete'                : function() {
                                                    $("#login_username").focus();
                                                },
    'onClosed'                  : function() {
                                                    $(".warningmsg").hide();
                                                    $(".errormsg").hide();
                                                    $(".successfulmsg").hide();
                                                }
});

$("#register").click(function() {
    $("#login_form").hide();
    $(".registertext").hide();
    $.fn.resize(450,385);
    $("label").addClass("#register_form label");
});

$("#login").click(function() {
    $.fn.resize(400,250);
    $("label").addClass("#login_form label");
});

$("#register_form").bind("submit", function() {
    $(".warningmsg").hide();
    $(".errormsg").hide();
    $(".successfulmsg").hide();
    if ($("#realname").val().length < 1 || $("#password").val().length < 1 || $("#username").val().length < 1) {
        $("#no_fields").addClass("warningmsg").show().resize(inherit,405);
        return false;
    }
    if ($("#password").val() != $("#password2").val()) {
        $("#no_pass_match").addClass("errormsg").show().resize();
        return false;
    }

    $.fancybox.showActivity();

    $.post(
        "../../submit.php",
        { realname:$('#realname').val(),
          email:$('#email').val(),
          username:$('#username').val(),
          password:MD5($('#password').val()),
          rand:Math.random() }
        ,function(data){
            if(data == "OK"){
                $(".registerbox").hide();
                $.fancybox.hideActivity();
                $.fn.resize(inherit,300);
                $("#successful_login").addClass("successfulmsg").show();
            }
            else if(data == "user_taken"){
                $.fancybox.hideActivity();
                $("#user_taken").addClass("errormsg").show().resize(inherit,405);
                $("#username").val("");
            }
            else {
                $.fancybox.hideActivity();
                document.write("Well, that was weird. Give me a shout at webmaster@criticalwire.com.");
            }
            return false;
        });

    return false;
});

$("#login_form").bind("submit", function() {
        $(".warningmsg").hide();
        $(".errormsg").hide();
        $(".successfulmsg").hide();
        if ($("#login_username").val().length < 1 || $("#login_password").val().length < 1) {
            $("#no_fields").addClass("warningmsg").show().resize(inherit,280);
            return false;
        }

        $.fancybox.showActivity();

        $.post(
            "../../admin/users/login_submit.php",
            { username:$('#login_username').val(),
              password:MD5($('#login_password').val()),
              rand:Math.random() }
            ,function(data){
                if(data == "authenticated"){
                    $(".loginbox").hide();
                    $(".registertext").hide();
                    $.fancybox.hideActivity();
                    $("#successful_login").addClass("successfulmsg").show();
                    parent.document.location.href=pasturl;
                }
                else if(data == "no_user"){
                    $.fancybox.hideActivity();
                    $("#no_user").addClass("errormsg").show().resize();
                    $("#login_username").val("");
                    $("#login_password").val("");
                }
                else if(data == "wrong_password"){
                    $.fancybox.hideActivity();
                    $("#wrong_password").addClass("warningmsg").show().resize();
                    $("#login_password").val("");
                }
                else {
                    $.fancybox.hideActivity();
                    document.write("Well, that was weird.");
                }
                return false;
        }); 
    return false;
});

});
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<p><a class="iframe" id="login" href="/login/">Login</a></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
$('#fancybox-frame').contents().find('#login_username').focus();
```

in your `onComplete`, or simply add a `$('#login_username').focus();` in a `$(document).ready();` of your actual login page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using an iframe then these may not work for you. We set up our fancybox to target a div which is contained within a hidden div on the page.

Calling focus() on a hidden element on $(document).ready() doesn't work. Binding to the fancybox onComplete event didn't work because the event was fired on page load, rather than when the fancybox was actually shown.

In the end what worked for us was binding to the mouseleave event of the fancybox anchor. So something like:

`$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#LoginLink').mouseleave(function () {
  $('#UserName').focus();

 });
});`